# How do I fix height = 0 of flex box child on Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

Flexbox child height always 0 inside flexbox container on safari. See https://jsfiddle.net/webiator/5mgfrksz/. Bottom should be green (as it is in Chrome)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body{
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .top {
            display: block;
            background: yellow;
        }

        .middle {
            background: red;
        }

        .bottom {
            background: green;
            display: flex;
            height: 180px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <p>Top</p>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        <p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p><p>Middle</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <p>This should have a height of 180px. Instead it is 0 for Safari.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried applying `flex-shrink: 0` to the `.bottom` container?

Comment: Wow thank you @Michael_B! Works like a charm. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Huh, this must work because Safari has different flexbox defaults than the other browsers....